# How to move to a specific page in a pageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a `pageViewController` embedded in a `Container` in a `ViewController` used as a Home Screen. The ViewController have several buttons to open other ViewController.

I am looking for a way to update the `pageViewController` current page based on a value of a variable set when saving data at a different ViewController. I managed to get the value to the Home `ViewController` and able to almost made it work with this code at the `viewDidLoad` for the Home `ViewController`

```
if currentStatPage > 0 {
    startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(currentStatPage) as ViewControllerDashboardCharts
    viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)
    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as! [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    var pageController = UIPageControl.appearance()
    pageController.currentPage = currentStatPage

}
```

The problem is that is I select the button that will show page #3 ( sending the value 2), the pages in the pageViewController get out of order ( the 1st page gets to the place of the 2nd page).

Is there a way to preload the 6 ViewControllers (dynamically created) and programmatically move to the specific one?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `presentationIndexForPageViewController`. I had a code that was returning 0, when changed the return value to the current page index, the problem was gone.

```
func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return currentStatPage

}
```